# Sharepoint 2013 - when user login give a new session token and expire all previous tokens

Tags: c#, .net, session, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint 2013 application and need to prevent users from login from differents places at same time.

Searching for a good solution I found out that giving a new session token each time the user login is a good solution. Also I will have to expires all older tokens from that user.

How can I do this using c#.Net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a lot of solutions to this. I've tried to deal with Sessions, Cookies without success.

My solution was to use some way of verification like IP for instance.
After check the IP (if the user IP changed) the program redirects the user to the following page:

> [sharepointsite]/_layouts/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

This page is from olders versions of Sharepoint and is hidden in the 2013 version.
It forces the user to log in again.

Here is some code example:

```cs
if(currentIP != lastIP)
{
   updateIP(currentIP);
   Response.Write("<sharepointsite>/_layouts/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true");
}
```

I know this is not the best solution, but was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like in normal ASP.NET app, the only difference would be to use session start from HttpModule, not from global.asax.

In your case do following:

- Create custom IHttpModule

```
public class CustomSessionHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        IHttpModule httpModule = context.Modules.Get("Session");
        var sessionModule = httpModule as SessionStateModule;
        if (sessionModule != null)
        {
            sessionModule.Start += OnSessionStart;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    private void OnSessionStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if user has active session( in your storage) if yes then invalidate it or block new request
    }
}
```

- Add module to the web.config in the farm with SPWebConfigModification to
  configuration/system.webServer/modules view feature (as a PoC do it manually)
- Ensure that session is enabled in the web.config (as far I remember this is required)

Comment: Hi @igby .

Thanks for helping but this doesn't worked, nothing happened.

I've solved this problem with another approach. I'll post here as answer